# How to change password reset link in Laravel5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos6, laravel-5.3

I made password reset with php artisan make:auth.

I know password reset link in the variable that called $actionUrl

That generate link like this.

```
http://example.com/program/password/reset/73d9b7b71a1782476dcd12fa438b839fc0a8aed1b7bfe1fad7d5c6909e45c11b
```

What I wanna do is change link like this.

```
http://example.com/program/admin/password/reset/73d9b7b71a1782476dcd12fa438b839fc0a8aed1b7bfe1fad7d5c6909e45c11b
```

I think that link is composed by href + token.
So I try to make custom link, but that is wrong work.

app/User.php -- change mail body from vendor view to own view

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\CustomPasswordReset;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new CustomPasswordReset($token));
    }
}
```

app/Notificantions/CustomPasswordReset.php -- show own view to email body

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class CustomPasswordReset extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->view('admin.emails.password');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

resources/views/admin/emails/password.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ url('/admin/password/reset', csrf_token()) }}">{{ url('/admin/password/reset', csrf_token()) }}</a>
```

Where should I change?

Comment: Its mentioned in the docs. `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#password-customization`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem for myself.

Here you can change variable $actionUrl.

app/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\CustomPasswordReset;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new CustomPasswordReset($token));
    }
}
```

app/Notificantions/CustomPasswordReset.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword; // add this.

class CustomPasswordReset extends ResetPassword // change extends from Notification to ResetPassword
{
    /**
     * The password reset token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $token;

    /**
     * Create a notification instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->view('admin.emails.password')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('admin/password/reset', $this->token)); // add this. this is $actionUrl
    }
}
```

resources/views/admin/emails/password.blade.php

```
Password Reset Mail View bla bla bla... No need Doctype or html or body tag.
$actionUrl display like this http://example.com/admin/password/reset/61afe571218324aab602e4a0d9054d2bb2039e886addef7f072c01fc9f155264
<br />
<a href="{{ $actionUrl }}">{{ $actionUrl }}</a>
```